# A SQL query retrieve same line several time

Tags: mysql, sql

I create a web page to display information from a database. The recovered data comes from five different tables. However, the SQL query sends the same line several times *(5900 lines in the DB, 24000 on the page)*.

I tried with the classic JOIN, LEFT JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN but I still get the same result.

Here is my MySQL query:

```
SELECT
   vs.Nom_VS,
   vs.IP_VS,
   vs.Port_VS,
   f5.Cluster_F5,
   pa.Nom_partition,
   po.Nom_pool,
   me.IP_membre,
   Port_membre
FROM VS_F5 vs
JOIN F5 f5 ON (f5.id_F5 = vs.id_F5)
JOIN Partition pa ON (pa.id_partition = vs.id_partition)
JOIN Pool po ON (po.id_pool = vs.id_pool_pool)
JOIN Membres_F5 me ON (me.id_pool_pool = vs.id_pool_pool)
```

As I said, I retrieve 24000 lines while the DB only contains 5900 lines. I really don't understand why I get the same result with different JOIN.

Hope you can help (and sorry if this is a stupid mistake).

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ...`  ?

Comment: tell us the nature of relation among VS_F5, F5, Partition, Pool and Membres_F5 tables

Comment: A general note, you should always start your join from the table which contains the direct data and then left join those tables from where you need to bring indirect data, that way you don't risk having multiple rows with NULL values of indirect data

Comment: Usually when you get extra rows from a join, it has to do with not having a full unique key as the join condition.  Try building up the query by starting with one table and adding each table/join one at a time to see which join condition is causing the duplication.

Comment: This isn't something we will be able to answer without seeing some sample data. The best we can say is that you have a 1:many relationship in one or more of these tables being joined and so you are getting more results then you anticipate.

Comment: @Mark I can't use DISTINCT, some value are the same.

Comment: @Learner Here is a [screenshot of the database structure](https://imgur.com/a/g6y7YCJ)

Comment: After some tests, it's appear that the problem come from the `JOIN Membres_F5 me ON (me.id_pool_pool = vs.id_pool_pool)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok that was just a problem in the db. Sorry